# Proof that interior is largest open subset.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to show that if $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $S \subseteq X$, then the interior of S is the largest open subset of $S$. We defined the interior to be the union of all open sets in $S$. I thought as follows,

Let $\{F_i\}_{i\in I}$ be the family  of all open sets contained in $S$. We've defined
$$
 \textrm{int}(S) = \bigcup_{i \in I} F_i
 $$
Because arbitrary unions of open sets remain open, we know that $\textrm{int}(S)$ is an open set contained in $S$. Furthermore because any open set contained in $S$ is some $F_i$, we have that $F_i \subseteq \textrm{int}(S)$ for all $i \in I$, therefore it is the largest open set contained in $S$.

Let me know if there are any issues. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is correct. It works for arbitrary topological spaces, not just metric spaces.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes. If $F$ is any family of sets and $\cup F\in F$ then $\cup F$ is the $\subset$-largest member of $F.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purpose of removing this from unanswered, yes the proof is correct (Erik D, DanielWainfleet) and the approach works for arbitrary topological spaces as mentioned by Erik D. Specifically if $(X,\tau)$ is a topology and $A \subset X$ the same idea works.